# Best way to replicate a table from a database that lives on another server

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I want to to completely copy a table from some sql database to my local. My question is that, is there an easy way to achive so. Since the table is much big I have to do this operation in a few steps by selecting from one database and then inserting it. I could not use file operation since this operation will be a part of web application and the remote database is the database of some user.

Comment: Are you replicating from MySQL to Postgresql, or the other direction Postgresql to MySQL ?

Comment: My local database is postgresql but the users database could be either mysql or postgresql.

Comment: See: [postgresql export database with command or pgAdmin III](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112102/postgresql-export-database-with-command-or-pgadmin-iii)